# How show progress indicator in callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

I have a progress indicator like this:

HTML code (in Webform2.aspx) :

```
<div>
        <div class="spinner">
            <div class="bounce1"></div>
            <div class="bounce2"></div>
            <div class="bounce3"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

and the css :

```
.spinner {
        margin: 100px auto 0;
        width: 70px;
        text-align: center;
    }

        .spinner > div {
            width: 18px;
            height: 18px;
            background-color: #333;
            border-radius: 100%;
            display: inline-block;
            -webkit-animation: bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out;
            animation: bouncedelay 1.4s infinite ease-in-out;
            /* Prevent first frame from flickering when animation starts */
            -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
            animation-fill-mode: both;
        }

        .spinner .bounce1 {
            -webkit-animation-delay: -0.32s;
            animation-delay: -0.32s;
        }

        .spinner .bounce2 {
            -webkit-animation-delay: -0.16s;
            animation-delay: -0.16s;
        }

    @-webkit-keyframes bouncedelay {
        0%, 80%, 100% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
        }

        40% {
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        }
    }

    @keyframes bouncedelay {
        0%, 80%, 100% {
            transform: scale(0.0);
            -webkit-transform: scale(0.0);
        }

        40% {
            transform: scale(1.0);
            -webkit-transform: scale(1.0);
        }
    }
```

and i write this script in head of page by the name :Webform2.aspx

```
 <script>
    $(window).load(function () {

        $('#spinner').fadeout(2000);
    });
</script>
```

and i have a button in another page by name :Webform1.aspx , and in OnClick() i have :

```
   protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect("webform2.aspx");
    }
```

i want when user click on Button1, it shows progress indicator till Webform1.aspx have loaded! How can i do it?

Comment: What is your question on this? Don't you know how to animate the scrollbar or do you not know how to listen on the event progress?

Comment: I want when user wsa responded to another page, it shows a progress indicator to him

Comment: yes i understood that. But i asked what your problem is exactly. Dont you know how to do the css or don't you know how to get the current progess value?

Comment: i dont know how to do my css..

Comment: I don't know whats your problem. Everything works. Here: http://jsfiddle.net/W86d6/

Comment: It works.. but i want to show this three circles till my Webform2.aspx have loaded.. not for ever..

Comment: If you do this: `$(window).load(function () {
        alert("test");
        $('#spinner').fadeout(2000);
    });` Does "test" get alerted when you expeted it to?

Comment: it doesn't give me any alert!!